# Move (drag-n-drop) object with keyboard arrow keys instead of mouse

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop, keyboard, arrow-keys

I have a 3rd party picture control in which I can draw shapes.  Through code, I'm loading a picture from disk and drawing a small square on the picture.  By default I can use the mouse to drag-n-drop  this square around the picture.  However, sometimes placing the square needs to be precise and it's difficult with the mouse.  I would like to use the keyboard arrow keys (or numeric keypad arrow keys if NumLock is off) to drag the square around (perhaps enter or space to drop it).

I have not found any "drag" methods of this object that would allow me to place it in a "dragging" mode.  So, I was wondering if I could simulate the mouse through code once the square is selected (click on).

So far what I've done is simply overridden the ProcessCmdKey function to capture the arrow keys of the numeric keypad so I can move the mouse around.  What I need to do though is simulate the mouse down at the same time and I'm not sure how to do that?  Perhaps a timer sending mousedown and then reading these?  Any help and examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    Dim bHandled As Boolean = False

    Select Case keyData
        Case Keys.Up
            If (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) = False) Then
                Cursor.Position = New Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y - 1)
            End If
            bHandled = True
        Case Keys.Down
            If (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) = False) Then
                Cursor.Position = New Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y + 1)
            End If
            bHandled = True
        Case Keys.Right
            If (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) = False) Then
                Cursor.Position = New Point(Cursor.Position.X + 1, Cursor.Position.Y)
            End If
            bHandled = True
        Case Keys.Left
            If (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) = False) Then
                Cursor.Position = New Point(Cursor.Position.X - 1, Cursor.Position.Y)
            End If
            bHandled = True
    End Select

    Return bHandled
End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any way to change the location of the square via code?  Perhaps you can give more info on the 3rd party library and show the code you use to load the image and the square?

Comment: @Idle_Mind - Thank you for the suggestion!  I was stuck thinking strictly on how it was being moved with the mouse that I did not consider attempting to reposition it via code.  I was able to successfully add code for the keyboard arrow keys to move the square.  Thank you very much.